# Haselbauer-Dickheiser Test no. 1: Matrix problem with four dots and tiles shifting colors

Tags: visual, sequence, progressive-matrix

This problem is the first problem from the [Haselbauer-Dickheiser Test](https://www.matrix67.com/iqtest/).

[image]

I find this to be one of the harder problems on the test that I haven't solved. To me, the test is weird in the sense that it contains some trivial problems, some well-known math results and some seemingly very hard problems.

Comment: So what would be Rot13(gur eryrinapr bs gur gvyr pbybhef, juvpu nyfb zbir/inel, ohg unir ab cynpr va na nafjre)?

Comment: The linked site says: "We ask that you do not share your answers in any public forum in order to maintain the integrity of the test". I don't think PSE's _explicitly stated_ policies forbid this sort of thing, but I think maybe they should; I'm going to put it on hold while we (the moderators and possibly the community) discuss this.

Comment: (Sorry, should have said lock rather than put on hold.)

Comment: Discussion at https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/puzzles-whose-creators-have-asked-them-not-to-be-shared -- general consensus seems to be strongly in favour of _not_ allowing this sort of thing. Sorry, HowDoICSharply!

Comment: I'm closing this because it's a puzzle whose maker has asked for answers to it not to be shared around; see [this meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/puzzles-whose-creators-have-asked-them-not-to-be-shared) for policy on this. Sorry!

Comment: (My apologies for the "off-topic" notice above; for technical reasons there are only a limited number of close-reasons available and that's the least inappropriate one. Of course it's not at all true that the question isn't about creation and solving of puzzles!)